# Plyer notification only sends through windows

Tags: android, notifications, kivy

I'm trying to send a notification on android but can't make it work. The notification sends fine on windows but it doesn't send at all on android. I am using Kivy Launcher to run my program. Will the notification only send after I have packaged the app? Thanks.

```
from plyer import notification as n
    n.notify(title='title', message='m', ticker='r')
```

Comment: take a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760144/kivy-and-android-notifications), there is already a solution for that

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Kivy and android notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760144/kivy-and-android-notifications)

Comment: Yes, plyer doesn't work correctly on android. I had the same problem. The possible solution is here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46760144/kivy-and-android-notifications